# Convexity/Concavity of this function

Tags: convex-analysis

How should I prove whether this function is convex or concave?

$f(\textbf{x}) = \frac{1}{x_1 + \frac{1}{x_2 + \frac{1}{x_3 + \frac{1}{x_4}}}}\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4_{>0}$

I tried to prove it by checking the definition of convexity:
$f(\lambda\textbf{x} + (1-\lambda\textbf{y})) \leq\lambda f(\textbf{x}) + (1-\lambda)f(\textbf{y})$.
But the definition of the function is so complicated that makes it hard to check the above inequality.
I even tried to check if $\nabla^2 f(\textbf{x})$ is positive semidefinite or not, but I didn't nail it.
Can someone bring any new and smart idea please?!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.